# Padding Variable Employee ID length with 9's

Tags: xslt

I have employee ids where the number of characters vary from 4 to 6. I want to have the final output length of 7. The employee id should be padded with 9's to the left.

Eg. Employee ID input

1234
23456
567894

Output Employee ID to look like

9991234
9923456
9567894

This is a Workday requirement.

Please can someone help with the XSLT statement for this.

Thanks

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: Oxygen is what I am using for my Testing. However how Workday does that internally I do not know.

Comment: You should find out, because it will come up with practically any XSLT question you might have. See here how: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring('9999999', 1 + string-length(@ID)), @ID)"/>
```